# Makefile multiple targets from same source file, with different flags

Tags: makefile, build, targets

I have a binary that I need to build multiple times with different compiler flags. Therefore, I have a Makefile that states something like:

```
OBJECTS_A := $(addprefix $(OBJFOLDER)/, $(SOURCES:.cpp=.a.o))
OBJECTS_B := $(addprefix $(OBJFOLDER)/, $(SOURCES:.cpp=.b.o))
OBJECTS_C := $(addprefix $(OBJFOLDER)/, $(SOURCES:.cpp=.c.o))
```

I also define a rule to change the flags for each OBJECTS_x:

```
$(OBJECTS_B): DEFINES+=-D_B
$(OBJECTS_C): DEFINES+=-D_C
```

And this is where the problem happens: If I state the targets separately, as:

```
$(OBJFOLDER)/%.a.o: %.cpp
    $(COMPILER) $(CFLAGS) $(INCFOLDER) $(DEFINES) -c $< -o $@

$(OBJFOLDER)/%.b.o: %.cpp
    $(COMPILER) $(CFLAGS) $(INCFOLDER) $(DEFINES) -c $< -o $@

$(OBJFOLDER)/%.c.o: %.cpp
    $(COMPILER) $(CFLAGS) $(INCFOLDER) $(DEFINES) -c $< -o $@
```

All works. However, if I merge all rules into one, only the first is evaluated:

```
$(OBJFOLDER)/%.a.o $(OBJFOLDER)/%.b.o $(OBJFOLDER)/%.c.o: %.cpp
    $(COMPILER) $(CFLAGS) $(INCFOLDER) $(DEFINES) -c $< -o $@
```

What I get on a dry run is that only $(OBJFOLDER)/%.a.o objects are build, but on the linking rule each binary requires its objects (and b and c binaries fail to build, therefore).

Any ideas?
Thank you!

Comment: A pattern rule with multiple target patterns means exactly as you've experienced: it expects a single invocation of the recipe to build _ALL_ the targets.  It's used when a program creates multiple output files.  See https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Intro.html (last paragraph)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve this using [secondary expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Secondary-Expansion.html) :

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:
$(OBJFOLDER)/%.o: $$(basename $$*).cpp
        $(COMPILER) $(CFLAGS) $(INCFOLDER) $(DEFINES) -c $< -o $@
```

Note that this is not a very idiomatic way of doing this, a more usual `define` / `call` / `eval` combo can be used to generate rules as in your first solution :

```
VARIANTS=a b c

DEFINES_FOR_a=
DEFINES_FOR_b=-D_B
DEFINES_FOR_c=-D_C

define make_target =
$$(OBJFOLDER)/%.$(1).o: %.cpp
        $$(COMPILER) $$(CFLAGS) $$(INCFOLDER) $$(DEFINES_FOR_$(1)) -c $$< -o $$@

endef

$(eval $(foreach variant,$(VARIANTS),$(call make_target,$(variant))))
```

Comment: Why won't the target-specific variable assignments work anymore?

Comment: My bad, it works perfectly well, I edited the answer

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to create symlinks to your source files and compile those with different flags. This way the same one generic pattern rule `(OBJFOLDER)/%.o: %.cpp` can build all of your targets:

```
OBJECTS_A := $(SOURCES:%.cpp=$(OBJFOLDER)/%.a.o)
OBJECTS_B := $(SOURCES:%.cpp=$(OBJFOLDER)/%.b.o)
OBJECTS_B := $(SOURCES:%.cpp=$(OBJFOLDER)/%.c.o)
$(OBJECTS_B): DEFINES+=-D_B
$(OBJECTS_C): DEFINES+=-D_C

%.a.cpp : %.cpp
    ln -s $< $@

%.b.cpp : %.cpp
    ln -s $< $@

%.c.cpp : %.cpp
    ln -s $< $@

$(OBJFOLDER)/%.o: %.cpp
    $(COMPILER) $(CFLAGS) $(INCFOLDER) $(DEFINES) -c -o $@ $<
```